# Fault: X509Token: An incorrect X.509 Token Type is detected

Tags: soap, cxf, soapui, x509, ws-security

I am trying to apply a WS Security Policy on my web services. The requirement is to sign the body and timestamp element (no encryption) with X.509 certificate. I am using SoapUI to sign and send soap messages. I implemented web services using cxf wsdl first approach.

I am getting **incorrect X.509 Token Type** from the server. Any suggestion to solve this ?

**The Policy**

```
    <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic128 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:Wss10>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss10>
        </wsp:All>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token11 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token
                                sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token11 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic128 />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:Wss11>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Wss11>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="InputBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body />
                <sp:Header Name="Timestamp"
                    Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" />
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OutputBindingPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body />
                <sp:Header Name="Timestamp"
                    Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" />
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

**The SOAP request message**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
     <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-83B479E74DEAAC133C142621373015110">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
           <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="bil soapenv" />
           </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
           <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
           <ds:Reference URI="#id-79B1EE1537BD34718D1426151592761356">
              <ds:Transforms>
                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="bil" />
                 </ds:Transform>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
              <ds:DigestValue>5sx0CDCmVVk5rCL+H/a7ePT4JLE=</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
           <ds:Reference URI="#TS-83B479E74DEAAC133C14262137301466">
              <ds:Transforms>
                 <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse bil soapenv" />
                 </ds:Transform>
              </ds:Transforms>
              <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
              <ds:DigestValue>KhSCUclKK36KDo/34E0KN17d974=</ds:DigestValue>
           </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>LHUjvdfQK0nvl3zwsLBfhfDMK856zXzCiqTnZX2QF5xPX+DA2GwSycZIqIx6gH3ofGUG67PqvHHYtczasH74RzLIO7V6Uq/t+r4NbcFhwVXV31tcYg/X+blCYvzhj31Y45qYQ/AlVcTy1Y2411V50T67HpAErt+Bj2C8PwxlB1LXhPBLSiD4pleUSlXEDtHE/tetC+FtAP7hNcFTHmp8M5amjLWsl52QdFHew8MIde8Xd/B6HatMEHUYmhI3urhuFoqrDXweL80gmI5njlWKUHIAFEPFjXfyEB2is9E4QQNiCbgT5L/VFnArc7uKjDt58Ctua/QB8QhEr3bMIlBJeQ=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-83B479E74DEAAC133C14262137301508">
           <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-83B479E74DEAAC133C14262137301509">
              <ds:X509Data>
                 <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=client</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>1166791595</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                 </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
              </ds:X509Data>
           </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
     </ds:Signature>
     <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-83B479E74DEAAC133C14262137301466">
        <wsu:Created>2015-03-13T02:28:50.146Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2015-03-20T01:08:50.146Z</wsu:Expires>
     </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-79B1EE1537BD34718D1426151592761356">
  <bil:Echo>
     <parameters>
        <Version>123</Version>
        <CorrelationId>1234</CorrelationId>
        <Message>hello</Message>
     </parameters>
  </bil:Echo>
</soapenv:Body>
```

**The SOAP response message**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
  <soap:Fault>
     <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>These policy alternatives can not be satisfied 
{http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702}X509Token: An incorrect X.509 Token Type is detected
     </faultstring>
  </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy says that the initiator token (signature token) must always be included to the recipient. However, your message only references the signature token via IssuerSerial.

Colm.